# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.ibm.mq.MQQueueManager (initialization failure)

Tags: java, ibm-mq

I was trying to send the message to IBM MQ with binding mode option, but getting

`java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.ibm.mq.MQQueueManager (initialization failure) error.`

I have added the below jars and details

- MQ Version : 8.0.0.7
- Default : Yes
- Status : Running
- Jars (from MQ installation directory):

  1. `com.ibm.mq.allclient-8.0.0.11.jar`
  2. `com.ibm.mq.commonservices.jar`

Did I miss anything here ?

```
ServletWrappe E com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper service Uncaught service() exception thrown by servlet action: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.ibm.mq.MQQueueManager (initialization failure)
        at java.lang.J9VMInternals.initialize(J9VMInternals.java:175)
        at com.bus.retail.service.invoker.nativemq.MsgReqRes.createConnectionFactory(MsgReqRes.java:32)
        at com.bus.retail.web.CustomRequestProcessor.process(CustomRequestProcessor.java:57)
        at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(ActionServlet.java:1913)
        at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doGet(ActionServlet.java:449)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:575)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:668)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1233)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:782)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:481)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.handleRequest(ServletWrapperImpl.java:178)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.invokeTarget(WebAppFilterChain.java:136)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:97)
        at com.bus.retail.web.ParamWrapperFilter.doFilter(ParamWrapperFilter.java:81)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:195)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:91)
        at com.bus.retail.web.flow.FlowFactory.doFilter(FlowFactory.java:110)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:195)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:91)
        at com.bus.retail.web.RootRequestFilter.doFilter(RootRequestFilter.java:137)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:195)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:91)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.doFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:967)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters(WebAppFilterManager.java:1107)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.handleRequest(WebApp.java:4047)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebGroup.handleRequest(WebGroup.java:304)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:1016)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.handleRequest(WSWebContainer.java:1817)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.ready(WCChannelLink.java:213)
        at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:463)
        at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleNewRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:530)
        at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.processRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:316)
        at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.ready(HttpInboundLink.java:287)
        at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.sendToDiscriminators(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:214)
        at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.complete(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:113)
        at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:175)
        at com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217)
        at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture$1.run(AsyncChannelFuture.java:205)
        at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1892)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax.resource.ResourceException
        at java.lang.J9VMInternals.verifyImpl(Native Method)
        at java.lang.J9VMInternals.verify(J9VMInternals.java:94)
        at java.lang.J9VMInternals.initialize(J9VMInternals.java:169)
        at com.ibm.mq.MQQueueManager.<clinit>(MQQueueManager.java:164)
        at java.lang.J9VMInternals.initializeImpl(Native Method)
        at java.lang.J9VMInternals.initialize(J9VMInternals.java:235)
        at com.bus.retail.service.invoker.nativemq.MsgReqRes.createConnectionFactory(MsgReqRes.java:32)
        at com.bus.retail.web.CustomRequestProcessor.process(CustomRequestProcessor.java:57)
        at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(ActionServlet.java:1913)
        at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doGet(ActionServlet.java:449)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:575)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:668)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1233)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:782)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:481)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.handleRequest(ServletWrapperImpl.java:178)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.invokeTarget(WebAppFilterChain.java:136)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:97)
        at com.bus.retail.web.ParamWrapperFilter.doFilter(ParamWrapperFilter.java:81)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:195)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:91)
        at com.bus.retail.web.flow.FlowFactory.doFilter(FlowFactory.java:110)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:195)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:91)
        at com.bus.retail.web.RootRequestFilter.doFilter(RootRequestFilter.java:137)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:195)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:91)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.doFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:967)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters(WebAppFilterManager.java:1107)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.handleRequest(WebApp.java:4047)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebGroup.handleRequest(WebGroup.java:304)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:1016)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.handleRequest(WSWebContainer.java:1817)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.ready(WCChannelLink.java:213)
        at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:463)
        at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleNewRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:530)
        at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.processRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:316)
        at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpICLReadCallback.complete(HttpICLReadCallback.java:88)
        at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:175)
        at com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217)
        at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture.fireCompletionActions(AsyncChannelFuture.java:161)
        at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncFuture.completed(AsyncFuture.java:138)
        at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.complete(ResultHandler.java:204)
        at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.runEventProcessingLoop(ResultHandler.java:775)
        at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler$2.run(ResultHandler.java:905)
        ... 1 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.resource.ResourceException
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:602)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassHelper(ClassLoader.java:777)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:750)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:341)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:731)
        ... 46 more
```

Below is the code snippet and I am getting the error in starting line itself.

```
            MQQueueManager qMgr = new MQQueueManager(""); 
            int openOptions = MQConstants.MQOO_INPUT_AS_Q_DEF;           
            MQQueue reqQueue = qMgr.accessQueue(reqQ, openOptions);          
            MQQueue resQueue = qMgr.accessQueue(repQ, openOptions);
```

Comment: Show your code.   Try adding jms.jar as well.

Comment: 7z l *.jar | grep -P com.ibm.mq.MQQueueManager

Comment: Also use an IDE like Eclipse to warn you of missing dependencies.

Comment: @user1133275 I am using eclipse and did not see any warnings. more over build was successful. I have included jms.jar as well but no luck

Comment: I suggest you run you program and add `-verbose:class` to the java execution, this will output all java jars that are loaded. Search this output for `com.ibm.mq` and ensure you only have the instances you mention in your question. Also it appears you are using IBM MQ classes for Java in the code posted but the error pasted mentions `createConnectionFactory` which would seem to be a reference to IBM MQ classes for JMS. If you are using JMS somewhere else, you would need to ensure you have `jms.jar` that is v2.0.

Comment: If you have a mixture of jar files from different versions of MQ it can cause problems. Do you have any other mq jars in the classpath? Note most start with com.ibm.mq* but the are others that are Oracle provided jars: `jms.jar` as mentioned must be 2.0 for mq v8 or later. If you use binding files there is also `fscontext.jar` and `providerutil.jar`. Note versions of IBM MQ prior to 8.0 also included `connector.jar` and `dbhcore.jar`, these are no longer required for v8.0 or later, I have had issues if older verions of these are in the classpath with v8/v9.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After removing the jars which were added in JVM classpath, then it started working :)

Problem was, there were multiple versions of JARS thats the reason It did not work

Comment: Assuming my comments to your question helped you resolve this, I will write up the details in my comments as an answer if you will accept it.

Answer (score 0):

The last "caused by" says

> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.resource.ResourceException

so you need a JAR containing at least this class, for example [this one](http://central.maven.org/maven2/javax/resource/javax.resource-api/1.7.1/javax.resource-api-1.7.1.jar).

Answer (score 0):

This is odd. The error is clearly a classpath error, either your class path does not point to the bindings mode .jar file or you don't have it.

If you are developing in eclipse then the IDE should be pointing this out to you. The java shouldn't compile, but you are not seeing IDE errors suggests that the IDE can find the appropriate jar file.

In which case I am guessing that you are not launching your application from the IDE, but are packaging it and deploying on a MQ server. If its to run in bindings mode then it has to run on a MQ server.

Check the class path and the `-cp` option to ensure that the .jar files that Eclipse says are required by your application are present in your runtime environment.

Comment: Yes, seems like class path issue and I am packaging it in EAR file and deploying on a MQ server. I have mentioned all dependencies through pom.xml and build is successful as well.  Still getting error